# How To Validate Captcha Form In Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, captcha

how to validate a captcha form in django?

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from captcha import fields
class Cap(forms.Form):
    cap=fields.CaptchaField()
```

template renderer function in views :

```
def cap(request:HttpRequest):
    return render(request,"cap.html",{"form":Cap})
```

template :

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.cap}}
        <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
    </form>
```

where to use `form.is_valid()` function in views?

Comment: Assuming you're using [django-simple-catchpa](https://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) you should be able to [validate](https://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#validate-the-form) it just like any other form.

Answer (score 2):

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()

    google_recaptcha_token = cleaned_data.get('g-recaptcha-response')
    if not google_recaptcha_token:
       raise ValidationError("Captcha Verficiation not submitted.")
    recaptha_status = json.loads(
       requests.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
                data={
                    'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
                    'response': google_recaptcha_token}).text
        )
    if recaptha_status['success'] == False or recaptha_status['success'] < 0.5:
       raise ValidationError("Captcha Verficiation failed.")
```